# How do I change the color of my background smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the code in question - https://codepen.io/illpill/pen/VbeVEq

```
function newColor() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length));
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
}
```

Right now that is the newColor() function...

When the button clicks, I'd like it to smoothly transition into the next quote as opposed to abruptly loading it. I'd also like for the quote to fade into white and then into a new quote... How is this achieved? Is it better to use jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: All you need is to put a `transition` style to the `body` element. You can do something like this: `body {
  transition: background-color 1s linear;
}`

Comment: *"I'd like it to smoothly transition into the next quote as opposed to abruptly loading it."* - Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code for that directly in the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add transition to your body for `background-color` property.

```
body {
  transition : background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

To add transition to any element you should write,

```
element-selector {
  transition: [CSS property] [duration] [timing-function];
}
```

For heading tags it will be

```
h3,h4 {
  transition: [css property] [duration] [timing-function]
}
```

> Transition only works when there is a change in the CSS property specified for the given element.

Comment: The same doesn't seem to work for the transition of the quote/h3

Comment: If you want it for h3 you'll have to write a separate transition for it.

Comment: @pmath325 edited my answer. I can be of more assistance if you could be specific about your requirement.

Comment: ah okay.. breaking it down like that helps a lot more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to fade the background (like others have shown here), but you'll have to use JavaScript to fade the text in and out.
Here's a [working version with the quote and author fading](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmxoyr) between random states:

```
$('#quote').fadeOut(400,function(){
  $(this).html(quotes[randomNumber][0]).fadeIn();  
});
$('#author').fadeOut(400,function(){
  $(this).html(quotes[randomNumber][1]).fadeIn();  
});
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! I guess I need to brush up on my jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Keep your code as is and add a css property:

```
.your-element-selector {
  transition: all ease 500ms;
}
```

Or with JS:

```
document.body.style.transition = 'all ease 500ms';
```

Comment: How come this doesn't work the same with the h3 element?

Comment: Just change the selector to h3 or select by class name or id, instead of body

Comment: Right, I thought that too but for some reason this isn't working

Comment: #quote {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 transition: all ease 2000ms;
}

    <h3 id="quote" class="text-center"></h3>